# How can I use php to search multiple key words in xml file and return the containing tag?

Tags: php, xml, search, keyword

I have an xml file like this, which stores video subtitles:

```
<videos>
    <video>
        <id>1</id>
        <enSub>Hello Foo! Good morning!</enSub>
        <cnSub>你好 Foo! 早上好！</cnSub>
    </video>
    <video>
        <id>2</id>
        <enSub>Hello Bar! Good afternoon!</enSub>
        <cnSub>你好 Bar! 下午好！</cnSub>
    </video>
</videos>
```

I want to search certain keywords through this xml, like I enter "hello moning" in the search text area, and the search result could find the video element with id "1".

I guess that using php xpath can only find single keyword in the xml file, and it has to iterate through the whole tree. I'm not confident that I can write a function with good performance.

I tried to use external resource like google custom search to search my web, but it turned out that I'm not using pages to display each video. I pass different video id as parameter to the video-play-page.

I also thought of regular expression, but don't know how to handle the orders of keywords.

So is there any search engine that I can use to search multiple keywords to pinpoint a video. I designed this to help my users to quickly find the video the watched.

I googled a lot. It's really slow, sometimes I just can't access google, in my place in China here. I tried "multiple keywords search xml" as searching keywords. Maybe my English isn't intelligent enough for google to understand my intent. I hope you guys here understand my question.

Thank you so much!!

Comment: Thank you! @Nouphal.M. I was really careless, didn't check my xml tags. But don't worry. In my projects, all tags are ok.

Comment: Unrelated, but here you have a hassle-free approach: http://fsockopen.com/php-programming/your-final-stop-for-php-xpath-case-insensitive

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please see my example code below on how to accomplish this.

```
<?php
$xml = <<<XML
<videos>
    <video>
        <id>1</id>
        <enSub>Hello Foo! Good morning!</enSub>
        <cnSub>你好 Foo! 早上好！</cnSub>
    </video>
    <video>
        <id>2</id>
        <enSub>Hello Bar! Good afternoon!</enSub>
        <cnSub>你好 Bar! 下午好！</cnSub>
    </video>
</videos>
XML;
// Lowercase the XML so we can do a non-case-sensitive search.
$xml = strtolower($xml);
// Create a DOMDocument based on the xml.
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadXML($xml);
// Create an xpath based on the dom document so we can search it.
$xpath = new DOMXpath($dom);
// Search for any video tag that contains the text good morning.
$nodes = $xpath->query('//video[contains(.,\'good morning\')]');
// Iterate all nodes
foreach($nodes as $node){
    // find the ID node and print its content.
    var_dump($xpath->query('id',$node)->item(0)->textContent);
}
```

-- Edit

I reread your post and it looks like you're using keywords and not strings. If that's the case, then try this snippet on for size:

```
<?php
$xml = <<<XML
<videos>
    <video>
        <id>1</id>
        <enSub>Hello Foo! Good morning!</enSub>
        <cnSub>你好 Foo! 早上好！</cnSub>
    </video>
    <video>
        <id>2</id>
        <enSub>Hello Bar! Good afternoon!</enSub>
        <cnSub>你好 Bar! 下午好！</cnSub>
    </video>
</videos>
XML;
// Lowercase the XML so we can do a non-case-sensitive search.
$xml = strtolower($xml);
// Create an DOMDocument based on the xml.
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadXML($xml);
// Create an xpath based on the dom document so we can search it.
$xpath = new DOMXpath($dom);
// Define the search keywords
$searchKeywords = array('good','hello');
// Iterate all of them to make them into valid xpath
$searchKeywords = array_map(
    function($keyword){
        // Replace any single quotes with an escaped single quote.
        $keyword = str_replace('\'','\\\'',$keyword);
        return 'contains(.,\''.$keyword.'\')';
    },
    $searchKeywords
);
// Implode all the keywords using and, you could change this to be
// an"or" condition if you so desire.
$searchKeywords = implode(' and ',$searchKeywords);
// The search keywords now look like contains(.,'good') and contains(.,'hello')
// Search for any video tag that contains the text good morning.
$nodes = $xpath->query('//video['.$searchKeywords.']');
// Iterate all nodes
foreach($nodes as $node){
    // find the ID node and print its content.
    var_dump($xpath->query('id',$node)->item(0)->textContent);
}
```

Comment: Hi @Kyle! thanks so so much! I tested your code in php sandbox. It works really well! I took an hour to study some functions unknown to me. Thanks! can I ask how this function will affect the performance of my php hosting server? Say I have 1000 users and 1000 <video>s, and they search by this function. Will it make my server really slow? I totally have no idea about performance. maybe I underestimate my hosting php server? Thanks!

Comment: hello @Kyle! Would you please teach me what does the dot, '.', in the contrains() function mean? I looked up the manual, should it be a str that contains a keyword?

Comment: Another question is that I load an xml file. How can I lowercase the whole xml file? Should I first load the xml and then $dom->saveXML($dom)? Thanks!!

Comment: Performance shouldn't be a huge deal. If you're worried, why not add 1000 videos and then use an application to hit your server a bunch of times. The '.' stands for current node. You can find more about it here: (http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/xpath_syntax.asp). As for lowercasing the entire xml file, you can either do it on the fly (as shown in my example), or you could do it manually to the file before uploading it to your server.

Answer (score 0):

First of all your xml is messy, the opening and closing tags has to match. You can use DomDOcument for manipulating xml.

```
$searchStr ="hello afternoon";
$searchArr = explode(" ",$searchStr);
$result = array();
$xmlData = "<videos>
    <video>
        <id>1</id>
        <enSub>Hello Foo! Good morning!</enSub>
        <cnSub>你好 Foo! 早上好！</cnSub>
    </video>
    <video>
        <id>2</id>
        <enSub>Hello Bar! Good afternoon!</enSub>
        <cnSub>你好 Bar! 下午好！</cnSub>
    </video>
</videos>";

$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadXML($xmlData);
foreach ($dom->documentElement->childNodes as $node) {
if($node->nodeType==1){
   $enSub = $node->getElementsByTagName('enSub')->Item(0)->nodeValue;
   $cnSub = $node->getElementsByTagName('cnSub')->Item(0)->nodeValue;
   $id = $node->getElementsByTagName('id')->Item(0)->nodeValue;
   foreach($searchArr as $key=>$val){
      $temp = array();
      if( strpos($enSub,$val) != false ){
          $temp[$id] = array(
             'id'=>$id,
             'enSub'=>$enSub,
             'cnSub'=>$cnSub
          );
          $result[$id]=$temp;
      }

   }
 }
}
echo "<pre>";
print_r($result);
```

You can find the working demo [here](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/81a31eaf15a6d2993f2b50e5f5b8e427c07e67f4)

Comment: Thank you so much! @Nouphal.M And thank you for the great php sandbox, i never knew that! Sorry couldn't accept two answers, but Kyle helped me to pinpoint a video ID by searching keywords both in cnSub and enSub.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you could use a search server like [ElasticSearch](http://www.elasticsearch.org/). Its using Lucene to index any kind of content. The indexed content can then be queried via a JSON API.

This of course only makes sense when you are constantly working with a large amount of data.

The other approach would be to parse the xml and build up an array which has each term in the sub-tag as an index. The value would then be an array containing the ids of the movies which have that term in their respective tag.
Basically you are building up a simple data index of your own.

You could then query your index like this:

```
<?php

$index = array(
    'Hello' => array(1,3),
    'World' => array(1),
    'Good' => array(2),
    'Morning' => array(2),
    'Vietnam' => array(2,3),
);

$searchTerms = array('Hello', 'World');

$found = null;
foreach($searchTerms as $term){
    if(array_key_exists($term, $index)){
        if(is_null($found)){
            $found = $index[$term];
        } else {
            $found = array_intersect($found, $index[$term]);
        }
    } else {
        $found = array();
        break;
    }
}

print_r($found);
```

The main benefit of this approach is that you would only have to traverse the xml document once while having a rather fast search. BTW - if you want to treat the search terms with OR instead of AND you can use array_merge and array_unique instead of array_intersect.

Somewhere in the middle would be the approach to set up a real database like [MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/) and do the above search in a query.

It really depends on what you want to accomplish.

Comment: Thank you! @Christoph Grimmer-Dietrich . sorry I'm new to php and xml, didn't use index before. and Kyle's answer already can do the thing. and I can understand his codes. Thank you all the same!

Comment: No problem, @LukeChen. Maybe somebody else finds my answer useful. Since SO is visited by so many people it might not be for naught :-)